# PHP mail form won't send input to email

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have a mail form that will not submit the input placed into the text area to the e-mail that I have inserted.
I am completely new to PHP.
This form has worked for me in the past.
I am trying to run the form from the freehostia.com server, I have the first upgraded plan which advertises SMTP.
Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">First name:
    <br>
        <input class="A" id="B" type="text" name="name" size="25">
    <br>
        E-mail:
    <br>
        <input class="A" id="A" type="text" name="email" size="35">
        <textarea id="A" name="message" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Please provide your information..."></textarea>
    <div>
        <input class="size" type="submit" value="Send!" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's my PHP content:

```
<?php
    $field_name = $_POST['name'];
    $field_email = $_POST['email'];
    $field_message = $_POST['message'];
    $mail_to = 'XXXX@XX.com';
    $subject = 'MESSAGE FROM SITE VISITOR ' . $field_name;
    $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
    $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
    if ($mail_status) { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.')
            window.location = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php }
    else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to XXXX@XX.com');
            window.location = 'contact.html';
        </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Everything appears to be in place to me. I can't for the life of me figure out what I have done wrong here.

Comment: Hey $mail_to must be the value you get from the field right? And what are these $email variables i cant see them being declared or initialized anywhere.

Comment: Is your form submitted normally, or by ajax/JavaScript? If the latter, it could be an issue of non-unique I'd.

Comment: @Sean It looks to me like normal submit. But the code has so many error and undeclared variables

Comment: It would help if you could add why you know it isn't working, such as any explicit error messages.  Did you get the "thank you" alert?  Or the "message failed" alert?  Or did it fail silently?

Comment: It returns the "message failed" alert.

Answer (score 0):

where is ur '$email' variable in,

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
```

where it initialized?

Answer (score 0):

go this website: https://github.com/HouKun1230/Jquery-mobile-with-PHP-MYSQL and look the email.php which is a email sending simple. It may help you.